# XSL Subtract Field Values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL document which I need to do a subtraction on.
I have 2 fields shown in the example below and I need to subtract them:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(argo:Document/argo:docBody/argo:wagonVisit/wagonLadenWeight/text(), '#', 'NotANiceNumber')
```

The above is the Laden Weight and from that I need to minus the below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(argo:Document/argo:docBody/argo:wagonVisit/wagonEmptyWeight/text(), '#', 'NotANiceNumber'
```

I am new to XSL and I am trying to pick apart someone else's code.

Thanks

Comment: Please state what exactly is your problem and post enough code to enable us to reproduce it: the source XML and the full XSLT (or at least enough of it to understand the current context and the decimal format you are using). As a general rule, you should perform numerical operation on the original values before formatting them (the result of formatting a number is a string, not necessarily a number).

Comment: If you don't have a way of obtaining the XML directly, You can probably temporarily replace your XSLT with an `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform` so that the output of your XSLT `is` the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<xsl:value-of 
    select="format-number(argo:Document/argo:docBody/argo:wagonVisit/wagonLadenWeight - 
                          argo:Document/argo:docBody/argo:wagonVisit/wagonEmptyWeight, 
                          '#', 'NotANiceNumber')" />
```

Or a bit cleaner:

```
<xsl:variable name="visit" select="argo:Document/argo:docBody/argo:wagonVisit" />
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($visit/wagonLadenWeight - $visit/wagonEmptyWeight, 
                                    '#', 'NotANiceNumber')" />
```

Comment: Just tried those, they looked spot on as well, but I am getting an error:  message=Error while converting document: java.lang.NullPointerException; Line#: 11;

Comment: That error seems to have nothing to do with whether my code above is correct. Can you show us the Java code that's involved here? Does your code run without error if you remove this part?

Comment: Ignore me, that was my error. I think its so close. I am getting a result of 0 when it should be more like 38,000. Thanks for your help on this, I really appreciate it

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us your input XML?

Comment: The input XML is sent from an application so I actually get no visibility of it unfortunately.

Comment: If you have your XSLT output `wagonLadenWeight` and `wagonEmptyWeight` by themselves, do you get the expected values for those?

Comment: Yep, the values are correct individually. The format of them is 'double'

Comment: After some manipulate I have managed to get this to work using your second lot of code. I appreciate your work! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
            <span>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(kssg:APrice/kssg:currentPrice, '0.00')"/>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td align="left">
                                <span>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(kssg:APrice/kssg:priceValue, '0.00')"/>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            
                            <td align="left">
                                <span>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(kssg:APrice/kssg:currentPrice - kssg:APrice/kssg:priceValue, '0.00')"/>
                                </span>
                            </td>
```

Comment: see my above code , I subtracted directly , it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).